# How to apply the same script for different sheets on the same spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheets document in which I need to run the same script separetely for each sheet, this script place a timestamp on column A whenever a cell is filled on column B

```
function onEdit(event)
{ 
  var timezone = "GMT-6";
  var timestamp_format = "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss"; // Timestamp 
  var updateColName = "ColumnB"; //Columna que es actualiza
  var timeStampColName = "ColumnA"; //Columna actualizada automáticamente
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1'); //Sheet 

  var actRng = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveRange();
  var editColumn = actRng.getColumn();
  var index = actRng.getRowIndex();
  var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var dateCol = headers[0].indexOf(timeStampColName);
  var updateCol = headers[0].indexOf(updateColName); updateCol = updateCol+1;
  if (dateCol > -1 && index > 1 && editColumn == updateCol) { // only timestamp if 'Last Updated' header exists, but not in the header row itself!
    var cell = sheet.getRange(index, dateCol + 1);
    var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, timestamp_format);
    cell.setValue(date);
  }
}
```

When I write another script for columnA, columnB and Sheet2, only puts the timestamp in sheet1, even when I write something on columnB from Sheet2.

Any suggestions?

One of the suggestions was this:

```
    function onEdit(event)
{ 
  var timezone = "GMT-6";
  var timestamp_format = "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss"; // Timestamp 
  var updateColName = "Timestamp"; //Columna que es actualiza
  var timeStampColName = "Ticket"; //Columna actualizada automáticamente
  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var actRng = event.source.getActiveRange();

  var editColumn = actRng.getColumn();
  var index = actRng.getRowIndex();
  var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var dateCol = headers[0].indexOf(timeStampColName);
  var updateCol = headers[0].indexOf(updateColName); updateCol = updateCol+1;
  if (dateCol > -1 && index > 1 && editColumn == updateCol) { // only timestamp if 'Last Updated' header exists, but not in the header row itself!
    var cell = sheet.getRange(index, dateCol + 1);
    var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, timestamp_format);
    cell.setValue(date);
  }
}
```

But it does not place the timestamp on the columnA.

Comment: where you call this function ?

Comment: Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, feel free to tell me. I would like to study to solve your issues.

Comment: The same keyword cannot be used for multiple function definitions - only one is kept.

Answer (score 2):

When the column B is edited, you want to put the timestamp to the column A for the edited sheet which has `ColumnA` and `ColumnB` in the cells "A1" and "B1". For example, when you edit the column B at Sheet1, it puts the timestamp to the column A of Sheet1. When you edit the column B at Sheet2, it puts the timestamp to the column A of Sheet 2. If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? I think that there are several answers for your situation. So please think of this as one of them.

#### From :

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1'); //Sheet 
var actRng = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveRange();
```

#### To :

```
var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
var actRng = event.source.getActiveRange();
```

If my understanding is not what you want, please tell me. I would like to modify my answer.

Comment: Yes, my goal is to write on cell in column B (sheet1) and set timestamp on column A (sheet1), and if I write on cell in column B (sheet2), to set timestamp on column A (sheet2).

Comment: @hkviktor Thank you for replying. I think that my modification works like that. Can I ask you whether this modification works at your environment? From your script, in order to work like that, the values of ``ColumnA`` and ``ColumnB`` are required to be put in the cells "A1" and "B1" for the sheets you want to use.

Comment: I tried your recommendation but it seems not to work, also, to clarify the part on the cells... let's say that I write on cell B45, then timestamp must my placed on cell A45 of the same sheet.

Comment: I get this error `TypeError: Cannot read property "source" from undefined. (line 7, file "AccTS")`

Comment: @hkviktor I'm sorry for the inconvenience. In my environment, I could confirm that the modified script works. So can you provide your current script? When you can do it, please update your question. I would like to solve your issue.

Comment: @hkviktor ``onEdit()`` is [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/). I'm really sorry. I had thought that you are using ``onEdit()`` as Simple Triggers. When the sheet is edited, ``onEdit()`` is run. I thought that you might directly run ``onEdit()`` at the script editor. If you directly run ``onEdit()``, such error occurs.  When you use this, please directly edit the column B of the spreadsheet. If you want to use ``onEdit()`` as both Simple Triggers and a normal function, please tell me.

Comment: I don't want them as Simple Triggers, just as a normal function

Comment: @hkviktor I'm sorry. I'm confused for your situation. You don't want to use Simple Triggers. But you are using ``onEdit(event)`` of the Simple Triggers. Can I ask you about the reason that you are using ``onEdit(event)``? I think that if you don't want to use the Simple Triggers, it is required to change the function name.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by creating a new project to copy the same code for a new page. Thank you very much for your assistance.

Comment: That sounds like a maintenance nightmare - two bound script projects for the same document, with marginally different code between them?

Comment: Maybe, but gave the chance to apply the codes for different sheets.